# in this code why does tellg function return -1?

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

I don't understand why in the bellow code tellg function return -1. I set offset into 0. but this code return -1. I expect this code return

```
0
0
```

but this code return

```
0
-1
```

why does the code return -1? note that the file has no byte(0byte).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void openIfstream(ifstream& stream);
int main() {
    ifstream is;
    char c[10], d[20];
    int loop = 0;
    openIfstream(is);

    while (loop != 2) {
        is.seekg(0);
        cout << is.tellg() << endl;
        is.read((char*)c, sizeof(c));
        is.read((char*)d, sizeof(d));
        loop++;
    }
    is.close();
    return 0;
}
void openIfstream(ifstream& stream) {
    stream.open("C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\xxx\\binary2.dat", ofstream::binary);
    if (stream.fail()) {
        cerr << "file can't be open" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think it should return 0?

Comment: At a guess the stream has failed at some point so `tellg` [will always return -1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) until the stream failure is cleared

Comment: is.seekg(0) is written. so it should return 0.

Comment: where has the stream failed? I don't know

Comment: Does your file contain at least 30 bytes?

Comment: no my file contain no byte

Comment: If you want to know where your stream is failing then check the stream is still `good` after each operation you perform on the stream

Comment: If the file has no bytes, then according to [the documentation to the read() function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), "*end of file condition occurs on the input sequence (in which case, setstate(failbit|eofbit) is called). The number of successfully extracted characters can be queried using gcount().*.  In short, and as mentioned, calling `seekg` and `tellg` on a stream in a failed state is not a good idea.

Comment: thank everyone that replied. 'calling seekg and tellg on a stream in a failed state is not a good idea' is good word thank you